# Cannot open batch file using System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

For some reason I can't get this batch file to run in my .NET 4.0 MVC3 project.  I am using server 2008R2 64 bit - does cmd.exe operate differently?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process1;
process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
string strCmdLine = "d:\audioTemp\test.bat";      
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdLine);
process1.Close();
```

Comment: the process1 code is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c d:\audioTemp\test.bat")
```

Comment: Thanks!  Knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Your string contains a tab character `\t`. Either escape the backslashes:

```
strCmdLine = "d:\\audioTemp\\test.bat";
```

Or use a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
strCmdLine = @"d:\audioTemp\test.bat";
```

Comment: For some reason it's just opening a blank cmd prompt and not passing the argument

Comment: I should add that strCmdLine works fine if I copy/paste into a cmd prompt